# The divergence of gravitational potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, poissons-equation

Is this computation of divergence correct?

$$\mathbf{g} = \frac{Gm\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = \frac{d}{dx}\mathbf{g}_x + \frac{d}{dy}\mathbf{g}_y + \frac{d}{dz}\mathbf{g}_z$$

$$r = |\mathbf{r}| = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\mathbf{g}_x = \frac{(Gmr^3 - Gmx(3/2)r2x)}{r^6}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\mathbf{g}_x = Gmr^{3 - 6} - 3Gmx^2r^{1 - 6}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\mathbf{g}_x = Gm(r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5})$$

Therefore:

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5}) + Gm(r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5}) + Gm(r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5})$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5} + r^{-3} - 3y^2r^{-5} + r^{-3} - 3z^2r^{-5})$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(3r^{-3} - 3x^2r^{-5} - 3y^2r^{-5} - 3z^2r^{-5})$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(3r^{-3} - 3r^{-5}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(3r^{-3} - 3r^{-5}(r^2))$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = Gm(3r^{-3} - 3r^{-3})$$

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g} = 0$$

Comment: This is almost unreadable. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn how to format it.

Comment: This is hard to read. I think you mean $\Delta$ instead of $\nabla$, ala https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation

 Aren't $\mathbf{g}$ and $ \Delta \mathbf{g}$ vectors? It is hard to tell if you have written this down.

Comment: The result is correct, the divergence of g is indeed zero (except at the origin)

Comment: Since this is an attempt to apply Poisson's equation, we should probably say that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf g = 0$ everywhere except inside a body of non-zero density. But if you are _inside_ a body of non-zero density then $\mathbf g \neq \dfrac{Gm \mathbf r}{r^3}$.

Comment: Regarding format, I think bold face for vectors is actually preferable to putting arrows over them. The real formatting problem is that you are trying to kludge math formulas using HTML and the Stackexchange markup for plain text. **Follow the link I posted before.** It shows you how to display very readable formulas, and with _much less effort_ than the methods you're using. (I know this because I've written math both ways.) In particular look at items 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, and 9 on that page; item 12 shows how to write $\nabla$ and $\partial$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you have chosen a poor example.

The formula $\nabla\cdot \mathbf g$ that you are trying to compute
is one side of [Gauss's law of gravity,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity#Differential_form)

$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf g = -4\pi G \rho.$$

In this formula, $\rho$ is the mass density at the point where you
compute $\nabla\cdot \mathbf g$.

The formula $\mathbf g = \dfrac{Gm \mathbf r}{r^3}$
can describe the gravitational field of a point-mass at $r = 0$.
It can be the field of a body of spherically-symmetric mass distribution
of radius $R$, but only when $r > R$.
In other words, the formula applies only in empty space, where $\rho = 0$,
and therefore we *should* find that $\nabla\cdot \mathbf g = 0$
wherever $\mathbf g = \dfrac{Gm \mathbf r}{r^3}$.

So Poisson's equation *is* true for this gravitational field, but
it is also trivial in this case.

To construct a non-trivial example to which to apply Poisson's equation,
why don't you try looking at the gravitational field *inside* a sphere
of radius $R$ with mass $m$ and uniform density $\rho_0$.
This field inside the sphere is $\mathbf g = Gm \mathbf r$.
Try calculating $\nabla\cdot \mathbf g$ for that case.